# Nothing happens when pressing button in cucumber, capybara test before adding sleep

Tags: button, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have a problem where I have a page with a kind of coupon that should change given several different button presses.

However, in one case, it seems that I am unable to click a specific button without adding a sleep between finding the element and pressing the button.

non working code:

```
element = page.find("[for='someButton']"])
element.click()
```

working code:

```
element = page.find("[for='someButton']"])
sleep 2
element.click()
```

I am wondering if there is anything I can do to remedy this issue without having to add a sleep, as I fear this makes my test more brittle as well as causing an unnecessary delay

PS.
No errors are being thrown and I did not write the web-application myself. I did however talk to the one who implemented this page and he said that there should not be anything special about this one button and that it should have it's event listener added as soon as the page loads

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get a timeout or click the wrong thing?

Comment: Absolutely nothing happens(I get no indication that anything went wrong in the console) and the test fails further down the line when I expect the coupon to have changed after pressing the button.

Comment: This issue now seems to have escalated and after an update of our single page application, finding and clicking a button directly after entering a new lobby on our application causes nothing to happen and I have been forced to add 1 second sleeps all over the place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen if the button is rendered in the DOM before the click event handler is bound. Capybara will be able to find the element as soon as it's in the DOM.

If this is the case, the tests are actually showing you that there is a (minor) bug. A real end user that clicked the button while the page is still loading would see the same result. A cleaner option would be to render the button via JavaScript and bind the click handler at the same time.

If changing the page isn't an option for you, there may still be hope. If there is something else on the page that is rendered by JavaScript in the same iteration of the event loop, you could add something to the test that looks for that before trying to click the button. For example, in the app I work on at my day job, we render an animated spinner GIF on the page when it loads, and then hide in in JavaScript when the page is fully loaded. Our Capybara tests wait for the spinner GIF to be hidden before interacting with the page.

Comment: Thanks, I've done some more testing and I can see that many of my tests complete before the page is actually properly shown. This makes it very probable that our tests try to click buttons before the page is properly loaded. We don't really have any spinning gif when opening anything but the front page of our web-app, but we do have a transitioning animation which I could try to wait for to finish instead.

Comment: Another variation of the of this would be to click the button, then in do an if/else statement checking for the result. If the result does not happen then retry. I had a similar issue where the button I was trying to click was not being loaded in time.